# download an article using DOI in R

Tags: r, wget, rcurl, doi

I have a DOI for an article, I am wondering if there are any R functions that can download the pdf file based on this DOI without the user having to download the pdf manually ?

Comment: I'm guessing you might struggle given that these articles are often behind paywalls if you don't have institutional access.

Comment: @thelatemail, lets assume that I have institutionalized access

Comment: If you tell us the DOI we might be able to figure out a method that works for that journal. A DOI in general doesn't have to have a PDF version so the general problem isnt solvable.

Comment: @Spacedman, for example `doi:10.7150/ijms.11309`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `httr` to see where that DOI points to by constructing a URL to `doi.org` and getting the headers:

```
library(httr)
headers = HEAD("http://doi.org/10.7150/ijms.11309")
headers$url
# [1] "http://www.medsci.org/v12p0264.htm"
```

In this case, the PDF seems to be at the same location as that page, but with a `.pdf` extension. But this is **not** true for all journals.

So for this journal, the PDF is at:

```
sub(".htm$",".pdf",headers$url)
# [1] "http://www.medsci.org/v12p0264.pdf"
```

So I can then do:

```
download.file(sub(".htm$",".pdf",headers$url),"paper.pdf")
```

to get the PDF.

Comment: high five thats perfect

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer:

Actually this is a difficult problem, and it's not related to R... can you show how to convert from a DOI to PDF in *any* language or setting?

The best I have been able to find is this:

[Crosscite](http://crosscite.org/cn/)

You can use curl (and presumably therefore `RCurl` or something) to query the crossref content negotiation system. This can return a citation for your DOI. From there, getting to PDF is hard though... at least you could get a URL to scrape for a PDF link, if you want to go that route.

This is the method used by jabRef to convert a DOI into a citation.

Things like Mendeley and Zotero have written parsers to go from web pages to PDFs. But I don't think there is some off-the-shelf ready-to-use way to do this.